# Происхождение слова "голгофа"

Tags: этимология

Предполагаю, что это искаженное русское слово "голова".

Comment: Голгофа - лобное место, со словом голова имеет смысловую связь.

Comment: Голгофа - лобное место, со словом голова имеет смысловую связь. Ещё есть смысловая связь выражений: " Салям Алейкум", "Шалом Алейхем" и заповедь Иисуса: "Приветствуйте друг друга христианским поцелуем" - челомкайтесь по русски. Gol, цель, чело,- из одного извода, так предполагаю.

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 5):

Как говорит словарь Брокгауза и Ефрона,
Голгофа — от древнеевр.(גּלגּלת) Gilgeiles-Golal. Гора, на которой был распят Христос, была частью холма Гареб. Из Гареба она только чуть-чуть выступала своей вершиной, чем-то напоминающей свод человеческого черепа. Такая схожесть с черепом и дала ей название Голгофа, ведь с арамейского Голгофа – это «череп». Другая версия: происходит от «Гол-Гофа», что означает «Гора Наказания» - лобное место (на этом месте происходили публичные казни).

Определение слова «Голгофа» по БСЭ:

Голгофа (греч. Golgotha, от арамейского гулгута, буквально - череп)
холм в окрестностях Иерусалима, на котором, по христианскому преданию, был распят Иисус Христос.

http://tolkslovar.ru/g3647.html

Позже в христианстве появились и закрепились еще два названия, обозначающие «череп» – «Кальвария» – латинское название и «Великий Кранион» – греческое. В древнерусский язык (Голгоθа) пришло из старославянского (Голъгота).

А голова, как и старославянское глава, восходит к  праслав. *golva-череп. Так что точки соприкосновения есть - смысловые, но нельзя сказать, что Голгофа - искажённое голова, оба восходят к черепу.

Answer (score 3):

По Фасмеру: от арамейского языка gûlgaltâ или иврита (גּלגּלת - gûlgelet) «череп». В ряде европейских языков слово заимствовано через латинский язык (Golgotha), куда в свою очередь пришло из древнегреческого (Γολγόθα) или непосредственно из греческого. Латинское слово Golgotha заимствовано из древнегреческого, Γολγόθα, или непосредственно из греческого. Древнерусское Голгоθа, как и старославянское Голъгота.

Answer (score 1):

См. [в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0).

Русское слово "голова" к "голгофе" не имеет вообще никакого отношения. Как и большинство библейских географических названий, оно ивритского-арамейского происхождения.

Answer (score 0):

Однако существует также лазо-мегрельская версия происхождении топонима Голгофи или на лазо-мегр. "Гольгота", что обозначает "гору ("Гол-", на лазо-мегр. "гольа-") с гротами (безчисленными, "-гота", на лазо-мегр. "готу(ль)а"), как народа  проживающего в регионе еще до прихода Исзраелитян.